# mern stack deployment issue using cPanel

Tags: node.js, cpanel, mern

Deployment is planned to be done using cPanel. I'm facing a issue in cPanel saying that Error: "can't acquire lock for app". This is error is raised when I run my website Node.js files. I'm able to successfully run a test app.js file but unable to run my website's app.js file. The website is developed using MERN stack.

Comment: Can you pass us your source code?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this while trying to get my MERN stack deployed.  (My app still isn't deployed, God help me, but I know the fix for the lock issue)

The cPanel support staff helped me with this.  There's a `.lock` file that was generated in your `/home/username` file directory (cPanel File Manager).

`.lock` has to be deleted.

Mine was located in `/home/username/nodevenv/repositories/appname`

Check your root directory for a `nodevenv` directory and follow the breadtrail from there.

Just delete it and that should fix your problem.